# R shinydashboard add a customized color for status parameter

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

So my question is very related to this one : [R shinyDashboard customize box status color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36080529/r-shinydashboard-customize-box-status-color)

However, the problem is that the provided solution does not add an available color but only replace an existing one. Thus, we are limited to only 5 colors for boxes in one shiny apps. In other words, I would like to add a customized color while keeping the existing ones

So i thought about a similar solution but it didn't work...

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        tags$style(HTML("
                        .box.box-solid.box-primary2>.box-header {
                        color:#fff;
                        background:#666666
                        }

                        .box.box-solid.box-primary2{
                        border-bottom-color:#666666;
                        border-left-color:#666666;
                        border-right-color:#666666;
                        border-top-color:#666666;
                        }

                        ")),
        fluidRow(
            box(width = 6, title = "youhou", status = "primary2", solidHeader = TRUE,
                "Box content"
            )
        )
        )
    )


server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

> Error in validateStatus(status) : 
>     Invalid status: primary2. Valid statuses are: primary, success, info, warning, danger.

Comment: `shinydashboard::box( )` has a color option, e.g., `background = "orange"`. How is this? The following is allowed;
                           ` # Invalid color: gray. Valid colors are: red, yellow, aqua, blue, light-blue, green, navy, teal, olive, lime, orange, fuchsia, purple, maroon, black.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below is a *hacky* way of doing it. Essentially you need to create a custom div and use it's `id` tag so that the `css` styling takes precedence over the original box styling and use `renderUI` to generate this new custom box.

However, you also do not want to inadvertently style the other `box` so you use the `id` to apply the styling specifically to your `box` of choice.

Finally you use `uiOutput` and `renderUI` on the server side to create this new `div` and the respective styled box.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(

      box(width = 6, title = "youhou", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
          "Box content"
      ),

      uiOutput("primary2")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$primary2 <- renderUI({
    tags$div(class = "another-box", id = "primariy2",
    box(width = 6, title = "youhou", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
        "Box content"
    ),
    tags$style(HTML("
                        #primariy2 .box.box-solid.box-primary>.box-header {
                        color:#fff;
                        background:#666666
                        }

                        .box.box-solid.box-primary {
                        border-bottom-color:#666666;
                        border-left-color:#666666;
                        border-right-color:#666666;
                        border-top-color:#666666;
                        }

                        ")) 
  )

  })

}
```